# Sublime Textをアップデートしたら Pretty Json が動かない

Tags: sublimetext

Windows で Sublime Text を使ってるんですが
Build 4126 にアップデートしたところ見た目がかなりかわったのはいいんですが
Pretty json が動かなくなってしまいました

---

`{"x":1, "y":2}`

という単純なJSONをかいて
右下をJSONモードとして認識させて
ちゃんと syntax hilight はきいてて色も変わってます

この状態でアップデート前は整形できてた Ctrl + Alt + J 押しても無反応になってしまいました

---

Pretty Json を packege control から remove
sublime １度閉じて開き直し
Pretty Json を packege control から install
sublime １度閉じて開き直し
してみましたが変わらず

同様の症状の方や解決法ご存じの方いらっしゃったら助けていただけるとありがたいです

---

設定はデフォルトのまま以下のようになってます

```
{
    "use_entire_file_if_no_selection": true,
    "indent": 4,
    "sort_keys": false,
    "ensure_ascii": false,
    "line_separator": ",",
    "value_separator": ": ",
    "keep_arrays_single_line": false,
    "max_arrays_line_length": 120,
    "pretty_on_save": true,
    "validate_on_save": true,
    "brace_newline": true,
    "bracket_newline": true,
    // Default: False
    // Valid Options: False, start, minimal
    "reindent_block": "minimal",
    // Name or Path to jq binary
    // Example: /usr/bin/local/jq
    "jq_binary": "jq",
    "jq_errors": false,
    "as_json": [
        "Packages/JSON/JSON.sublime-syntax",
        "Packages/PackageDev/Package/Sublime Text Commands/Sublime Text Commands.sublime-syntax",
        "Packages/PackageDev/Package/Sublime Text Settings/Sublime Text Settings.sublime-syntax",
        "Packages/PackageDev/Package/Sublime Text Menu/Sublime Text Menu.sublime-syntax"
    ]
}
```

１つ気になるのは設定ファイルに // でコメント入ってますが
sublime の設定ファイルはJSONを拡張した // をコメントとして扱ってくれるものなんでしょうか

また
`"jq_binary": "jq",`
ってなってますが windows terminal からたたいてもそんなコマンドありません
いままでは特にデフォルトのまま動いてたんですが外部の jq コマンドをいれないと動かなくなったんでしょうか

Comment: コマンドパレットから呼び出して整形が実行できるかと、キーマップの設定辺りを確認してみるとよいかもしれません。参考: [Sublime Text - JSON formatter shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34896840)

Comment: ビルド番号しか書かれていませんが、恐らく Sublime Text **4** でしょうか？

Comment: どこをみればわかるんでしょうか？　about や change log にはビルド番号しか書かれてないです

Answer (score 1, accepted):

理由は不明ですがキーバインドがパッケージをインストールしただけでは有効になっていなかったようです

コメント欄で言及のあった [Sublime Text - JSON formatter shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34896840) の内容を参考にして

Preference > Key Bindings

の中に

```
{ "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+j" ], "command": "pretty_json" }
```

を追加したところ元通り動くようになりました